# Java array error (2d array)

Tags: java, arrays, simulator, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an error when I run my Deer Simulator
here is the code

```
        public void comparegrassDeer()
        {
            int[] grasspos = new int[3];
            int[] deerpos = new int[2];
            for (int i = 0;i < aog; ++i)
            {
                grasspos = g[i].getpos();
                for (int j = 1; i <= aod;++i)
                {
                    deerpos = d[j].getpos();
                    if ((deerpos[0] >= grasspos[0]) && (deerpos[0] <= grasspos[1]) && (deerpos[1] >= grasspos[2]) &&(deerpos[1] <= grasspos[3]))
                    {
                        if (g[i].checkFood() != 0)
                        {
                            g[i].foodLoss();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            d[j].hunger();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The main problem is in the comparedeergrass method.
note it works when its compiled but creates an error when in the cmd window i type updatedeer. Creates array index out of bound error.

Comment: add the stack trace..

Comment: PLEASE USE CLASS NAME CONVENTIONS FOR YOUR CLASS NAMES. Also there is too much code that may not be relevant to the problem. Try including only the code that you think is causing the issue, along with the stack trace.

Comment: And respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter. Variables are camelCased.

Comment: *had to include all the code*. No you didn't. Read about [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), click "edit" and start deleting code

Comment: Could it be as simple as this typo: `deerSin.createDeer(501, 1);` which might have to be `deerSim.createDeer(501, 1);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grasspos` is an array with a length of 3. You call `(deerpos[1] <= grasspos[3])` which, i guess, is supposed to be `(deerpos[1] <= grasspos[2])`, since `grasspos[3]` would require an array with a length of 4.